# Link directly to change password form in B2C?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have a membership model where public signup is disabled, and we use the Graph API to create new users. I'm struggling to find a solution using custom policies that will somehow generate a link that can be emailed to new users. Upon clicking the link, they should be directed to the change password form - completely bypassing the one-time code step. Once they've entered and confirmed their password, their account is activated and they may then log in.

I've looked at the [sample flows](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples) but I can't find anything that matches. I've found a couple of comments in other threads that refer to having to implement such a solution outside of B2Cs custom policies, and use the Graph API to set the password and enable the account. But I thought the whole idea (and inherent complexity) of custom policies was that you could basically implement any kind of flow you can think of.

Anyone done something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is via a [magic link](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-magic-link) included in the email. The user in question is included in the JWT.

Refer [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-a-jwt-to-invoke-an-azure-ad-b2c-flow-using-id-token-hint-13752ee6d9df) as well.

Once the custom policy has received the link, call "LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId".

Comment: Good info! I'm not particularly familiar with B2C, so I can see I need to educate myself on how to call a technical profile...